# Does rust support const-generic types with a runtime-determined value?

Tags: rust, const-generics

Consider the classic example of a const-generic datastructure: a square matrix.

```rust
struct Matrix<T, const N: usize> {
    inner: [[T; N]; N]
}
```

I'd like to return a structure whose const parameter is dynamically defined:

```rust
fn read_matrix() -> ??? {
    let n: usize = todo!() // the N is decided dynamically
    let r: Box<Matrix<u8, {n}>> = todo!();
    r
}
```

but:

- Rust will complain that `n` is not a constant
- I cannot write an appropriate return type :`fn read_matrix<const N: usize>() -> Matrix<u8, N>` is not adequate, as it lets the caller choose the N, where I want N to be determined in runtime.

I can work around the second limitation by defining a trait:

```rust
trait DynamiMatrix {
   fn size(&self) -> usize;
   fn some_method(&self);
   ...
}

impl<T, const N: usize> DynamicMatrix for Matrix<T,N> {
   fn size(&self) -> usize { N };
   fn some_method(&self){ ... }
   ...
}
```

But, for construction, the best I can try is:

```rust
fn read_array_pair() -> Box<dyn DynamicMatrix> {
  let n: usize = todo!();
  let m = Box::new(Matrix { inner: [[0; n]; n] });
  todo!(); // fill up m
  m
}
```

and Rust will still complain that n is not constant.

Is there any way to achieve this? If possible without falling back to nested `Vec`s, because i'd like my square invariant to be enforced?

Comment: Even if Rust supported this feature (which I don't think it does) you could not bind a const generic to a variable declared with `let`: you'd need to make it a `const`. You can't have a const generic determined at runtime. Not without dependent types, anyway

Comment: In other words, rhetorically, Rust could support something like `fn read_matrix() -> Matrix<T; impl const usize> {...}` and the existential `impl const usize` could be determined by the content of the function: but it would still have to be compile-time resolvable to some particular `N`, so you couldn't run arbitrary code to compute it like you appear to be doing here.

Comment: @trentcl yeah, that's what I figured, but I hoped it would be possible to emulate even a limited form of dependent types using trait objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Const parameters were deliberately designed so that they are always known at compile time. Just like most information about types in a program, the compiler will erase them without keeping this information at run-time.
So the short answer is no, and it is unlikely that a direct means of specifying this kind of const parameter at run-time will ever be featured.

However, there are known workarounds to creating generic structures that may either contain compile-time or run-time information, and they even predate const parameters.

Consider this simplified definition of [`ndarray::ArrayBase`](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.15.3/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html):

```
pub struct ArrayBase<S, D> {
    /// Data buffer / ownership information. (If owned, contains the data
    /// buffer; if borrowed, contains the lifetime and mutability.)
    data: S,
    /// The lengths of the axes.
    dim: D,
    /// The element count stride per axis.
    strides: D,
}
```

This definition is parameterized over its *source of elements* `S` as well as its dimensionality `D`. `D`, often implemented through the primitive [`Dim`](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.15.3/ndarray/struct.Dim.html), will then be generic over both situations:

- For a fixed number of dimensions such as in [`Array2`](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.15.3/ndarray/type.Array2.html), `D` = [`Ix2`](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.15.3/ndarray/type.Ix2.html), enabling the user to pass a `[usize; 2]` to index an element in the array.
- If the number of dimensions is unknown at compile time, there is `ArrayD`, in which `D` = [`IxDyn`](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.15.3/ndarray/type.IxDyn.html) and users can pass anything which Deref's to a `[usize]` for indexing.

The conclusion is that you may be interested in changing the design of your structs and traits so that these details (whether inferred at compile-time or at run-time) are encoded in a *type parameter* instead of a const parameter.